# Is asking "Where can i find people that are x / to do y" a bad question?

Tags: discussion, questions

The title say everything. I've faced some questions like this some days ago, and another today, here, you can take it as example: [Where can I find some beginners to learn and work with?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15310/where-can-i-find-some-beginners-to-learn-and-work-with)

Also, you can see that its a community wiki question, is it right?

In my humble opinion, this kind of question is the same of those that people ask technology. Its such a pain to encounter some like those.

Here are another examples:

[Where to find designers for independent projects?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6105/where-to-find-designers-for-independent-projects)
[Where can I go to find a game graphic artist?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12846/where-can-i-go-to-find-a-game-graphic-artist)

Those below does not asks for people, but i think it falls in the concept.
[Trying to find a game development competition](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6427/trying-to-find-a-game-development-competition)
[Where can I find animated textures for free?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16806/where-can-i-find-animated-textures-for-free)

So when i see one of those, should i flag it or leave it okay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of these are at best borderline. While a few list-type questions are OK and generally acceptable, we don't want to encourage it.

There should only be one list question of each type. So there should be one for each kind of asset (textures, meshes, etc). All new questions are duplicates and should be forwarded to the master question.

Any "find people" question should be pretty much gone. That's not really something we can do, it has no factual answers, there is no single best answer, it's way too localized, etc. A list of game development competitions is borderline, but I would say that it's acceptable.

Also, making something Community Wiki does *not* mean it gets to break the rules.